# Looking for software: frame a TV feed with other information

Tags: video

***note:*** I looked on the other Stack sites and didn't see one where this question would be more appropriate -- please, no snipes

I'm looking for software that frames a TV feed (via coax cable) with still images, tickers, etc. Below is an example of a potential layout I'm interested in (care of Bloomberg).

[image]

Comment: I have a software that does something similar - it records a real-time video, is able to process the image (write to it, rescale, and such) and then archive or stream it to some windows media server.  Interested?

Comment: @Daniel, would it be able to output the processed stream to coax for a TV feed? Do it have a user-friendly interface? A non-techie would be using it.

Comment: Brat, shoot me an e-mail and we'll figure something out :)  www.videophill.com is the base

Answer (score 3):

This could be implemented very easy in [processing](http://processing.org/)

here is an example programm that integrates a live videostream, an infographic and
some text

```
import processing.video.*;

Capture video;
PImage cat;

void setup() {
  size(400,400);
  video = new Capture(this, 160, 120);
  textFont( createFont("helvetica", 15 ));
  cat = loadImage( "Buttered_cat.png");
}

void draw() {   
    if (video.available()) {
      background(0);
      video.read();
      text( "live videofeed", 20, 10 );
      image( video, 20, 20 );
      text( "Infographics", 270, 10 ); 
      image( cat, 270, 20 );
      text("long text with serious informations ...", 10, 200);
    }
}
```

to generate an window that looks similar to this one 
[image]

Comment: Well, here's an interesting application for you to build and you can apparently be first-to-market. I'm looking for someone I met who wanted to wrap his TV feed in his barber shop.